# Decidable? Turing machine runs X steps for certain input?

Tags: computer-science

Question is the following language decidable:

{(M)|given input "aaaaa" Turing machine M will perform at least 1295 steps}

I would say, yes it is. Just let the Universal Turing Machine count each step, and accept if it reaches step 1295.

But is this not a case where Rice´s theorem applies? Which means that we cannot decide such a property?

Comment: Your algorithm is correct. When you try to apply Rice's theorem, what property of languages are you using?

Comment: Oh...I guess the point is that the property is not one of the language but only of the turing machine? And Rice´s theorem only applies for languages.

Answer (score 4):

Rice's theorem cannot apply to machines, only to properties of languages (since the proof of Rice's theorem relies heavily on us being able to control the language which a machine accepts, although we have very limited control on what the machine does **until** it accepts).

So yes, as you've answered yourself, the language is decidable.